# BluetoothSocket connection 'Invalid Argument' error

Tags: python, bluetooth, rfcomm, pybluez

I am trying to connect and send data from my laptop to my Android phone via Bluetooth. I am using PyBluez library for that. When I am trying to call 'connect' method of BluetoothSocket:

```
sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
sock.connect((host, port))
```

it always gives me the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rfcomm-client.py", line 41, in <module>
    sock.connect((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

As I understood from docs and examples, the type of host should be String, and port should be int. That I checked.

I also checked the validity of both port and host, and already paired my devices.

Could anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: What are the values for `host` and `port`? As far as I can guess, that's where the error most likely orinates from.

Comment: @RomanRiesen I also think so. The address (as I found in examples), should be Bluetooth MAC address of the device as a String. Port should be integer. So the address is something like : 'zz:xx:cc:vv:bb:nn'